# MySQL return only those values that comes between starttime and starttime+x value

Tags: mysql, time, compare, datetime-comparison

I have a situation, where in column 'starttime' has unix timestamp stored.

Now, I want to select only those records where:

```
currentTime = time(); // unix timestamp
currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= (starttime + x)
```

Where `x` is dynamic range of some seconds.

Answer (score 0):

as I get form your question, what you need to do is

```
select * from table where xfield > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and xfield <= SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),x);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However I want something like: xfield > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() <= SUM(xfield,x) is this possible?